# Communication senario: A sends to B or B sends to A

Tags: parallel-computing, concurrency, process-algebras, message-passing

Consider processes A and B and the situation where either A will send a message to B or B will send a message to A. Is there a standard algorithm for this scenario that makes sure that exactly one of these two interaction took place?

In a naive implementation where both A and B decide independently whether to send or receive there is the case where both of them decide to send. In such a case the requirement of exactly one interaction is not met. Is there a correct implementation? Are there any references?

Comment: Are you asking for a concrete implementation, or an abstract model? If the latter, any process calculus with mixed sums does the job, e.g. $\overline{x}.P + y.P' \ \ |\ \ x.Q + \overline{y}.Q'$.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  What exactly are you looking for?  Note that implementation and coding questions are off-topic here.  See our [help/on-topic].  Please edit your question to clarify.  It might also help to describe what approaches you've considered and why you rejected them.

Comment: @Martin Berger, I am familiar with process algebra, and what I am looking for is an implementation of this exact situation

Comment: "EDIT" is not needed, there is revision history available. So are you looking for implementation (code in chosen programming language) or abstract model?

Comment: @Angelos Operating systems implement some of those, e.g. "select". But fully unconstrained non-determinism, is not easy to implement efficiently.